# Adding DIV on top of image div css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

Trying to add the text on top of the image. I tried adding relative and absolute positioning to the divs and z-index. Anyone know why its not working as intended?

```html
<div class="container banner bg-white">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 banner-image" style="position: relative;z-index:-1;">
          <img src="http://7-themes.com/data_images/collection/3/4446673-blue-wallpapers.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="banner-box-outer" style="position: absolute;">
          <h1 class="text-dark-blue">
            Some text
            <br> tittle
          </h1>
          <div class="banner-list">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <img src="https://" alt="Tick" class="banner-list-tick"> 1 point
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item" style="display:inline;">
                <img src="https://" alt="Tick" class="banner-list-tick"> 1 point
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">
                <img src="https://" alt="Tick" class="banner-list-tick">1 point
                <br><span style="font-size:12px; ">   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;som e text</span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Just declare `position: relative` to the containing parent element `.container.banner`, then add `top: 0;` to `.banner-box-outer` (which will now  offset its position to its nearest/closest *relative* parent).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to add `position: relative` to the parent of the element you are trying to position absolutely. This basically tells the absolute element to be positioned **relative to that parent**.
Css:

```
.container .row{
  position: relative;
}
.banner-box-outer{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```